# How can I convert DB2 TIMESTAMP to UTC milliseconds?

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a DB2 function to convert `TIMESTAMP` to `UTC milliseconds`?

Comment: are you trying to do this in just SQL?

Comment: @Lucas: Primarily Yes. However if required I can also create a local function as well.

Comment: Why?  And what's your application layer written in?  You may have best results/easiest effort if you store everything in UTC timestamps, then convert application-side only, with a good library (like [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), for Java).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you're looking to get the number of milliseconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00), there is not a built-in function to do this.

However it's trivial to create a UDF that can:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION utcmillis (in db2ts timestamp)
   returns bigint
   language sql
   deterministic
   no external action
   return (
      bigint((days(db2ts - current timezone) - days('1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000')) * 86400 + midnight_seconds(db2ts - current timezone))*1000 + microsecond(db2ts)/1000
   );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, days aren't always 86400 seconds long - your code is not DST safe.  Additionally, I'm not sure if how IBM handles timezones is correct, as they seem to be using only 'offset' definitions, which will treat all timezones in the same longitude the same; not all countries switch DST at the same time...  Additionally, this code may be presuming that incoming timestamps all include a time-zone, and are in the 'current' one - which may not be the case.  Now, if all timestamps were in UTC, and you didn't do anything with the timezone, this should probably work.

Comment: While you are technically correct that there are not always 86,400 seconds in a day, the logic in this UDF will produce the same value as a call to the UNIX `mktime()` function for a given date/time (excluding the milliseconds, of course, since `mktime()` doesn't have subsecond resolution).

Comment: As for timezones:  DB2 uses the `CURRENT TIMEZONE` special register to decide how to handle a timestamp value.  DB2 sets the value of the `CURRENT TIMEZONE` register by querying the operating system's time when an SQL statement is executed.  So, if you issue the statement `VALUES CURRENT TIMEZONE`, then modify the timezone on the database server, and execute the same `VALUES CURRENT TIMEZONE` statement again, DB2 will report the new timezone.

Comment: If `db2ts` is a local timestamp, and on a day during DST, then no, this doesn't give correct results - after all, the adjustment for timezone is only going to offset by a few hours, and the difference gets 'truncated'.  If it's a UTC timestamp, then timezone doesn't matter...

Comment: `CURRENT TIMEZONE` specifies the **current offset** from UTC, and the value for a system *will change* when DST starts or ends.  On my system the value is  currently `-80000`  (i.e. -8h, 00m, 00s). But as soon as we go on to DST, the `CURRENT TIMEZONE` register will immediately start returning `-70000`.

Comment: You're correct about it returning correct dates during UTC, I think I must have missed parsing the reference to `current timezone` inside the `midnight_seconds(...)` call.  However, the function is still assuming that the given timestamp is using the 'current'/'local' timezone (offset), which may not be the case.  Notably, if you pass in a timestamp that should be under the influence of DST, when the current system is not, the answer returned will be off by the relevant difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000861.htm).  Something like this:

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(1,CHAR(timestampField -
    TIMESTAMP('1970-01-01-00.00.00.000000')))
```

Assuming you mean milliseconds since unix epoch.  I did not test this, and you may have to adjust the value by some factor of 10 as the db2 documentation only says *Fractions of a second*.

Comment: Unfortunately.... no (I wish).  Two reasons - 1) The output of `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` is limited to 'INTEGER', which automatically limits the size it can be (for _seconds_ this means the end of the epoch is 2038). 2) The output of the difference of the two timestamps is an imprecise **interval**, which is why the function can only return an **ESTIMATE** (I mean, seriously, IBM?) - this is because interval is divorced from information that would help it determine needed information, like daylight savings time, or leap years.

Comment: `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` is, like, the worst thing ever.  A good rule of thumb is that you should never, ever use it.